# Fill a web contact form with Random Name, email, subject and message with Python

Tags: python

I need to create a python code that can fill out a web contact form with random data. The code should take emails from a JSON or text file, take names from a JSON or text file, messages from a list of messaged stored in messages.json or txt and same for "subject Field) and then visit a URL, fill these fields and then send the contact form,

we will set a limit to 20-30 contact form fills per time (day) and then it stops running, it will be ideal if it can send one form for every random amount of time between 30 Minutes to 2 Hours

My Code so far:

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

url = 'https://www.webiste.com/contact.php'

names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())

for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))

for email in emails:
    email_extra = email

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        sent_name = name_extra
        sent_email = email_extra
        subject = ''
        message = ''
    })

    print 'Form Filled and Submited'
```

Comment: You're not asking a question. Further: Start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, don't use Python 2 for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) library to generate fake data:

Install it using `pip install Faker`.

https://github.com/joke2k/faker

For more please refer :

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: I went through faker, but I do not see how I can implement it to send the form on the website. I do not just want to get the data but also submit the form. can you help?

Comment: are you doing something like scraping or automation testing?